# My anagram program does not work

Tags: java

For some reason when I run this program it doesn't work...
It is suppose to read from a text file containing a few words, and then print the anagrams of those words into a new file, each word and its anagrams into one line, and then the next word and its anagrams into the next line...

The example text input file contains

"hpesvy

wounxppzu

xznoug

ehsypv

zpwuonxpu

xrqryptcb

uzngxo

gzuonx

ysepvh

uozgnx
"

`Java Ass2 inputfile.txt output`

I get an error message "null"

and all compiles fine. I have no idea whats happening, can anyone help?

There code is in two files.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.*;


public class Ass2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length == 2){
            String inFile = args[0];
            String outFile = args[1];

            try{
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(inFile);
                LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);

                int linenumber = 0;

                while (lnr.readLine() != null){
                    linenumber++;
                }
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String strLine;
                String [] array = new String[linenumber];
                //Read File line by line
                int i = 0;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                    array[i] = strLine;
                    i++;
                }
                in.close();
                //String[] sorted = InsertionSort(array);
                //fileWrite(sorted, outFile);
                isAnagram(array);
            }
            catch(Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("I need 2 arguments");   
            }
    }

    private static void fileWrite(String[] array, String outFile) {
        BufferedWriter filewrite = null;
        try{
            filewrite = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(outFile));
            filewrite.newLine();
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                filewrite.write(array[i]);
                filewrite.newLine();
            }
            filewrite.close( );
            }
        catch ( IOException e){}        
    }

    public static char[] InsertionSort(char[] array){
        //Insertion Sort algorithm from class
        int j;
        for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++){
            char tmp = array[i];
            for(j=i; j>0 && tmp<array[j-1]; j--){
                array[j] = array[j-1];
            }
            array[j] = tmp; 
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void isAnagram(String [] sorted){
        Node[] linkedListArray = new Node[sorted.length];
        String tmp1 = "";
        String tmp2 = "";
        String [] myarray = new String [sorted.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length-1; i++) {
            for(int a=i+1; a<sorted.length; a++){
            tmp1 = sorted[i];
            tmp2 = myarray[a];

            if (tmp1.length() == tmp2.length()){
                 char [] a1 = tmp1.toCharArray();
                 a1 = InsertionSort(a1);
                 char [] a2 = tmp2.toCharArray();
                 a2 = InsertionSort(a2);
                 int j = 0;
                 boolean isAnan = true;
                 while (j<a1.length && isAnan == true){
                     if (a1[j] != a2[j]){
                         System.out.println(tmp1+ " is not An "+tmp2 );
                         Node newLink = new Node(tmp1);
                         linkedListArray[j] = newLink;

                    }
                     j++;
                 } 
            }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

.

```
public class Node {
        public String item;
        public Node next;
        public Node(String tmp1){
            this.item = tmp1;
        }
    }

    class InsertionSort{
        private Node head;
        public InsertionSort(){
            head = null;
        }
        public InsertionSort(Node[] linkedListArray){
            head = null;
            for(int j=0; j<linkedListArray.length; j++)
                insert( linkedListArray[j] );
        }
        public void insert(Node newNode){
            Node previous = null;
            Node current = head;
        while(current != null && current.item.compareTo(newNode.item)>0){
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        if(previous==null)
            head = newNode;
        else
            previous.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = current;
        }
        public Node nextNode(){
            Node temp = head;
            head = head.next;
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Post the error trace.

Comment: How can I debug this if I just run it on a terminal on a mac?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to show "solved" or include a solution (as it is then useless for future readers. Instead post an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :) See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3):

Bro, you're committing a cardinal sin.

```
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

That's completely hiding evidence of something wrong with your code. First thing you need to do is change that to this:

```
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Next thing wrong, you're handling an exception like this:

```
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
```

That's where your message (`Error: null`) is coming from, because a `NullPointerException` usually has no message. So, second thing you need to do is change that to the same thing `e.printStackTrace();`.

Then you will have complete information about what's going wrong.

This is by no means a comprehensive tutorial on proper exception handling in Java. I'm merely instructing you on the bare minimum information you need for debugging.

In truth, for what you're doing, you really shouldn't be catching any exceptions at all. You should get rid of your `try..catch` blocks and let any exceptions be thrown out of your `main` method like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
```

Comment: Ok thank you! So the error message is 



"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

 at Ass2.isAnagram(Ass2.java:114)

 at Ass2.main(Ass2.java:63)



"
So I'm still puzzled, the code has everything it needs it was working before and now its broken..

Comment: As @Marvin pointed out, the elements of your `myarray` haven't been initialized to `String` values, so the elements are `null`, so a `NullPointerException` is thrown when you attempt to call a method on a null reference.

Comment: I honestly spent hours on this code, I just don't get it anymore, how can I initialize the values so that they are strings within myarray?

Comment: Like everything is there to make this work, but when I put it all together last night it just didn't click.

Comment: The simplest thing you could do to prevent the NullPointerException would be `for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) { myarray[i] = ""; }`. However, your code would still not function as you intend. There is nothing in your `myarray` and I don't know what you wanted there. You're on your own from here.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in the `isAnagram` method. See the following extract:

```
    String[] myarray = new String[sorted.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int a = i + 1; a < sorted.length; a++) {
            tmp1 = sorted[i];
            tmp2 = myarray[a];

            if (tmp1.length() == tmp2.length()) {
```

`myarray` is an array consisting of only `null` values. Therefore `tmp2` will also be `null`, therefore `tmp2.length()` throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: But I need myarray here I can't get rid of it, it worked in my tutorial notes why doesn't it work here?

Comment: I believe you might want to initialize `myarray` with the values of `sorted`?

`String[] myarray = new String[sorted.length];`
`System.arraycopy(sorted, 0, myarray, 0, sorted.length);`

Comment: thanks, the code still doesn't work.. I will have to see my prof about this. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What would be your expected output?

Comment: It is suppose to out put a file whatever u want to call it lets say FileOutput, and in that file its the anagrams of the words in the example file input.. so if the example file had dog, cat, god, in it.. It would then compute that example and print out 

"dog god"
"cat"

In the out put file

Comment: There are several issues: You have an unused class (`InsertionSort`), the `fileWrite` method is commented out, your `isAnagram` method fills the `linkedListArray` variable without doing anything with it afterwards and there is an `isAnan` variable which probably shoud indicate anagrams, but is effectively unused. 

I started to fix your code, but quickly ended up rewriting most of the logic, so I guess that you indeed better discuss it with your prof. No offense, but there is some lack of comprehension which IMHO can better be solved face-to-face.

I'll still be here for discussions, though.